# Refreshing gridx cell value using DateTextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form, dojo.gridx

Working with gridx. I've added a Diji/form/DateTextBox to one of the columns.

I am able to save back to the grid's JSON, but I am not managing to update what is displayed in the cell.

```
function deadlineDecorator(value) {
    return '<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="constraints:{datePattern: \'dd/MM/yyyy\'}" data-dojo-attach-point="deadlineCal" required="true" />';
}

function <portlet:namespace/>deadlineCellValueSet(gridData, storeData, cellWidget) {    

    cellWidget.deadlineCal.set('value', newDate(gridData)); 
    cellWidget.deadlineCal.constraints.min = new Date();
}

var locale = dojo.require("dojo.date.locale");

function getDate(d){
    res = locale.format(d, {
        selector: 'date',
        datePattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
    });
    return res;
}

function deadlineChange(cellWidget, cell) {
    return [
        [cellWidget.deadlineCal, 'onChange', function(e){                                            
            cell.setRawData(getDate(cellWidget.deadlineCal.value));             
        }]
    ];
}
```

I am creating the grid using this:

```
data = [{"id": 1, "dead": 18/12/2014}];

function creategrid() {
    var gridData = {data: data};
    var dataStore = new dojo.store.Memory(gridData);
    grid.setStore(datastore);


};
```

How can I save the chosen date back to the JSON AND show that change in the cell.

I guess I could refresh the whole grid, but that doesn't seem like a very elegant solution?

Comment: Do you have a backing data store, or are you populating the grid some other way?

Comment: @vansimke I am populating the data using

Comment: ??? your comment seems to have been truncated

Comment: @vansimke Sorry, realised it would be easier to edit. I have now edited my original post.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the store in a dojo/store/Observable and then updating the record with a "put" call to it? Haven't used GridX, but that is the canonical way to make stores signal when they have been updated.

Comment: Thanks vansimke, I will give that a go. However, I am reasonably certain that it's a Gridx issue. Specifically the decorator that is being called by the structure.

Comment: I went here: http://oria.github.io/gridx/demos/cellWidget.html and manipulated the underlying store and it updated the progress bar. Code that I ran was:
- s = store.get(1)
- s.Progress = 0.8
- store.put(s)

It updated the progress bar as expected. Could you do the same with your app?

Comment: @vansimke - Thanks for the help. I have fixed it. gridData was a string but DateTextBox needed a Javascript date.